# SQL Server Configuration Error while Installing Redmine using Helicon Zoo Web Installer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, rake, redmine, heliconzoo

I have tried installing Redmine using MS Web Platform and from Helicon Zoo Web installer. I am using Windows 7 machine 64-bit and SQL server 2008. I have configured database.yml to connect to my SQL server DB and I m trying to migrate from SQLLite(default db) to SQLSERVER. Here is my configuration set up

```
production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: RedMineDB
  host: XX.XX.XX.XXX/SQLEXPRESS
  username: slquser1234
  password: testpwd
```

Here is the error trace :

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\REDMIN~1>rake db:setup --trace
** Invoke db:setup (first_time)
** Invoke db:schema:load_if_ruby (first_time)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:create
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Server name not found in configuration files
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68:in `connect'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1-x86-mingw32/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68:in `initialize'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:417:in `new'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:417:in `connect'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:204:in `initialize'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:40:in `new'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:40:in `sqlserver_connection'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `table_exists?'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:75:in `get_primary_key'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:60:in `reset_primary_key'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:49:in `primary_key'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:13:in `attributes_protected_by_default'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:216:in `block in protected_attributes_configs'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:188:in `yield'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:188:in `default'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:188:in `protected_attributes'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:118:in `block in attr_protected'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:117:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:117:in `attr_protected'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/redmine-test/app/models/issue_relation.rb:73:in `<class:IssueRelation>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/redmine-test/app/models/issue_relation.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:514:in `load_missing_constant'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/redmine-test/lib/redmine/helpers/gantt.rb:28:in `<class:Gantt>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/redmine-test/lib/redmine/helpers/gantt.rb:21:in `<module:Helpers>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/redmine-test/lib/redmine/helpers/gantt.rb:19:in `<module:Redmine>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/redmine-test/lib/redmine/helpers/gantt.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/redmine-test/lib/redmine.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/redmine-test/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/redmine-test/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prerequisites'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/REDMIN~1/GEM_HOME/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => environment
```

Answer (score 0):

My first advice is to address this issue to support@helicontech.com.
And please clarify the following points:

the error is "Server name not found in configuration files", which means that Zoo is working but something is wrong with database connection, so

1. make sure that "rake db:setup --trace" is executed from Zoo console tun from manager.
2. make sure that in web.config you have
3. read the docs to tiny_tds https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds
   :dataserver - Can be the name for your data server as defined in freetds.conf. Raw hostname or hostname:port will work here too. FreeTDS says that named instance like 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS' work too, but I highly suggest that you use the :host and :port options below. Google how to find your host port if you are using named instances or go here.